# Problem with tikzpagenodes and minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, tikzpagenodes

Using the anchors defined by [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) inside a `minipage` produces unexpected results; this is not the case for the `current page` family of anchors defined by standard TikZ as the following example shows.

Labels in `cyan` correspond to the standard TikZ anchors which are correctly positioned ("cp" stands for "current page"); labels in orange  correspond to `tikzpagenodes` anchors which are correctly positioned ("ta" stands for "text area"); labels in red correspond to `tikzpagenodes` anchors which are *not* correctly positioned since the anchors were called from withing a `minipage` ("ta" stands for "text area"). The [`showframe`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe) package was used to have a visual guide of the page layout; the `minipage` also was framed for reference

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \Anchor in {north,west,south,east}
{
  \node[font=\color{orange}] at (current page text area.\Anchor) {ta.\Anchor};
  \node[font=\Huge\color{orange}] at (current page text area.\Anchor) {X};
}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\frame{\begin{minipage}[c][4cm][c]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \Anchor in {north,west,south,east}
{
  \node[font=\color{cyan}] at (current page.\Anchor) {cp.\Anchor};
  \node[font=\Huge\color{cyan}] at (current page.\Anchor) {X};
  \node[font=\color{red}] at (current page text area.\Anchor) {ta.area.\Anchor};
  \node[font=\Huge\color{red}] at (current page text area.\Anchor) {X};
}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can the correct anchors defined by `tikzpagenodes` be recovered when used inside a `minipage`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the `fit` library to define a global *"good"* `current page text area`:

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
\node[fit=(current page text area),line width=0,inner sep=0,name=good current page text area]{};
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\centering
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
\node[fit=(current page text area),line width=0,inner sep=0,name=good current page text area]{};
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \Anchor in {north,west,south,east}
{
  \node[font=\color{orange}] at (current page text area.\Anchor) {ta.\Anchor};
  \node[font=\Huge\color{orange}] at (current page text area.\Anchor) {X};
}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\frame{\begin{minipage}[c][4cm][c]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \Anchor in {north,west,south,east}
{
  \node[font=\color{cyan}] at (current page.\Anchor) {cp.\Anchor};
  \node[font=\Huge\color{cyan}] at (current page.\Anchor) {X};
  %\node[font=\color{red}] at (current page text area.\Anchor) {ta.area.\Anchor};
  %\node[font=\Huge\color{red}] at (current page text area.\Anchor) {X};
  \node[font=\color{blue}] at (good current page text area.\Anchor) {ta.area.\Anchor};
  \node[font=\Huge\color{blue}] at (good current page text area.\Anchor) {X};

}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It produces two misplaced blue X and no orange ?

Comment: @Tarass This example requires **two** compilations.

Comment: I didn't know. Works fine. Sorry. Should I delete the first comment ?

Comment: @Tarass The first compilation warns: _"LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right"_. Leave your first comment: it can serve other people. ;-)